# DNS setup from Cloudflare to Amazon API Gateway

Tags: dns, amazon-cloudfront, cloudflare, aws-api-gateway

I have a website mydomain.com with the DNS configured through Cloudflare. I am in the process of setting up an API accessible through api.mydomain.com

The servers I use are hosted on Digital Ocean, but I would like to use some of the features of the Amazon API Gateway Interface (I will later be migrating all servers over to Amazon). The API server is the same as the  website (again this will later be separated, but for now the effective A record is the same Digital Ocean node). The API Gateway Interface is configured and I can access it just fine through the provided endpoint someamazonendpointurl.com/stage

On Amazon I have created a Cloudflare distribution with origin api.mydomain.com. It has some basic HTTP to HTTPS behaviours along with query string parameters. I then set a CNAME record on Cloudflare to point to the endpoint URL. When I try and access api.mydomain.com though I get the Chrome error:

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Does anyone have any idea what I might have misconfigured. I realise this is a bit of an odd setup, but it is a stop-gap while we migrate our servers over to amazon.

**UPDATE**

I noticed I had a CNAME record in cloudfront to api.mydomain.com. I've now removed this but get:

```
ERROR

The request could not be satisfied.

Bad request. 
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: <id>
```

Comment: I am from API Gateway. Could you give the raw request/response (including all headers) from the endpoint?

Comment: @AbhignaNagaraja I have the same problem, and I'm getting the "Bad request" error.

Headers: https://gist.github.com/ile/496714ae00f6c4a4048bd84d3f5bf34e

Comment: I'm guessing the Host header offends the API Gateway.

Answer (score 8):

Most likely you have your SSL mode on Cloudflare set to "Flexible", which doesn't use https to connect to the origin server.  API gateway tries to redirect non-secure requests, so you have a redirect loop.

Set your SSL mode to "Full" and you should be good to go!  You can do this on the "Crypto" tab of the Cloudflare dashboard.

Comment: I posted a full setup guide as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45849093/3769905) to another question

Comment: Unfortunately my main website doesn't have SSL enabled (which is why I'm using CloudFlare in the first place).