# Redirect my sub.my-domain.com to discord

Tags: redirect, dns, weebly

I've been looking for a method with DNS to redirect my domain's subdomain e.g `http://server.my-domain.com` to `https://discordapp.com/invite/server`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As i found the answer of this question, i'd love to share it with all of you,

1. Create a **CNAME** on your domain named **server**: (or any other name you want)
2. Target the CNAME to: `discord.gg.opts-slash.INVITECODE.redirect.center` but change the **INVITECODE** to your server invite code
3. Save it and you are good to go!

Please note that:
If you want to use it for another method other than discord please remember:

**.opts-slash** means **/** for example you have `http://example.com/123`, to redirect your `http://example.my-domain.com/` to `http://example.com/123` type in the **CNAME** `example.com.opts-slash.123.redirect.center` and your **CNAME** name to example.

Comment: I was confused and used it wrong. But ran into this. [Redirect Center Link](http://redirect.center/) EDIT: I thought that was why it was not working. But it appears they are redirecting me to adds and spam when I tried using this method. So it seems they blocked it or found a way to foil it. They do only want domains to be used for partners.

Comment: careful `discordapp.gg` is a fake website. also, DNS names are not case sensitive so you should URL encode the invite code but still. for me it doesn't work

Comment: Invites are case sensitive.. the website makes it lowercase bruh

Comment: I'm redirect.center's maintainer. You can now use uppercase. Go to the website and use the URL converter.

Comment: Thank you so much @UdleiNati! If anybody has trouble finding the form, it's under the 4th accordion on redirect.center. Paste in the full invite link (e.g. https://discord.com/invite/InViTeCoDe) and it'll generate a lowercase CNAME value.

Answer (score 3):

As i couldn't get it to work redirecting it directly through a CNAME, i had success by creating a simple netlify app which is just redirecting via JS:

1. Create index.html with the following content:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Discord redirect</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    window.location.replace("https://discord.com/invite/INVITECODE");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

2. Place the index.html inside a folder and upload it to netlify
3. You'll get a unique name, such as **eloquent-noyce-x00xx0**
4. Set a CNAME to your app with **eloquent-noyce-x00xx0.netlify.app.** (last dot is important!)
5. Set your *mydiscord.mydomain.com* as custom domain in netlify
6. That's it, visit *mydiscord.mydomain.com* and it'll redirect you

Answer (score 1):

It works for me thanks full tutorial in case someone understood it.

**This is for CloudFlare**

Created Add Record "A"

this type "A" must contain in Name: "Name you want for the sub domain", and in IPv4 address they must place "8.8.8.8", Proxy status activated.

[IMG Add Record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YtzR.png)

Then they go to "Rules"

Here they add a Create a new rule, and place the following data in URL: "yoursubdomanin.yourdomain.com", luen in Then the settings are: Select "Forwarding URL", then in Select status code: Select "301 - Permanent Redirect"

in Enter destination URL (required) you put the url of the Discord invitation: "https://discord.gg/yourInviteCode".

[IMG Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBufr.png)

That's how it works, in case it doesn't load you because you have already tried many methods with "discord.yourdomain.com", try another subdomain while the other one is reactivated or try from another device, example of another dub domain "discord1. yourdomain.com".

**That's bye :D**

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been looking for a solution like this.

Answer (score 0):

For me redirect like previous answer doesn't work.
Free (minus the domain name) and easy solution is to use Amazon Web Services. Create an AWS account and follow this guide:

https://kennbrodhagen.net/2016/04/02/how-to-return-302-using-api-gateway-lambda/

---

Then use Route53 to create a CNAME to redirect to the API Gateway:

[How to CNAME to Amazon API Gateway Endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36737313/how-to-cname-to-amazon-api-gateway-endpoint)

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a Discord invite that never expires.

2) Use the .GG URL to find the .COM URL. You will be redirected in the browser when you paste the .GG URL into the browser.

https://discord.gg/abc12de (redirected to) -> https://discordapp.com/invite/abc12de

Note: abc12de (example) stays the same between the two URLs.

3) In your GoDaddy domain, scroll down and to the right. Select Forwarding.

4) FORWARD TO: (Drop down) https:// (fill in box) discordapp.com/invite/abc12de <- Note: remove https from the original URL.

5) FORWARD TYPE: Permanent (301)

6) SETTINGS: Forward Only

7) Save and wait.

8) You'll notice a new A Record is created with a TTL of 600 seconds. This shows your settings have taken and should now work.

URL with additional info: https://www.godaddy.com/help/forward-my-domain-12123

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
Create a "A" DNS Record with name "discord" pointing to 8.8.8.8
Create a page rule of url forwarding to your server invite called "discord.mydomain.com"
The CNAME way doesn't work!