# How to route mywebsite.com to AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-api-gateway

I have a domain registered with godaddy (mywebsite.com). I have my site on api gateway (backed by lambda)

I have setup the custom domain in AWS API Gateway and updated CNAME in godaddy's DNS to point to the api gateway domain name and it all works for when I type "www.mywebsite.com". But when I type "mywebsite.com" without the www, it doesnt go there.

What am I supposed to do to get this to working. I tried adding forwarding from root to [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com), but smoehow that didnt work as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

IF the problem is the www, you should point the mydomain.com to AWS using "CNAME" or "A" then add a CNAME of www pointing to mydomain.com.

so, in your DNS table:

mywebsite.com CNAME points to: **apigatewayid**.execute-api.**us-east-1**.amazonaws.com

Then www points to mywebsite.com.

That way, you can acces mywebsite.com/stagename/apiendpoint or... [www.mywebsite.com/stagename/apiendpoint..](http://www.mywebsite.com/stagename/apiendpoint..).

**It SHOULD WORK, but... I just saw this thread**:
[How to CNAME to Amazon API Gateway Endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36737313/how-to-cname-to-amazon-api-gateway-endpoint)

Maybe you have to use the Route51:

Another way of doing it (but of course, for a cost):

- ADD the main domain or a subdomain to Route 51
- create the certificate
- add a mapping domain on API Gateway
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html